# How to include two controller in url in codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, codeigniter-3

I want to include two controller in a url. Ex. domian.com/category/js/topic/promise. In this, category and topic are controllers and js is argument of category controller, and promise is argument of topic controller.

I have searched, and doesn't found any related example like it. So, How can I achieve this type of url which contains two controller url? I am using codeigniter 3.

```
/* code of category controller*/

class Category extends MY_Controller{

    public function index($category = null){

        if($category == null){
            // here show all categories using model
        }

        else{
            // show topics of given category
        }

    }

}
```

```
/* code of topic controller */

class Topic extends MY_Controller{

    public function index($topic = null){

        if($topic == null){
            // here show all topics using model of the selected category
        }

        else{
            // show data of selected topic
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you already written these two controllers? Could you show what they look like?

Comment: @Marleen, I have added both controller codes

Comment: Do you also want to be able to display topics without selecting a category, for example: `domain.com/topic/promise` to show `promise` topics in all categories? Or do you always need to select a category before you can select a topic?

Comment: @Marleen, Yes, I want to include category as well in the url. I know it's easy to display topic directly using controller.

Answer (score 0):

To use your `Topic/index` method with your desired url structure, you need to add the following to `config/routes.php`:

```
$route['category/(:any)/topic/(:any)'] = "topic/index/$2";
```

- `domain.com/category` will then show all categories
- `domain.com/category/index/js` will show all topics in a specific category
- `domain.com/topic` will show all topics in all categories
- and both `domain.com/category/js/topic/promise` and `domain.com/topic/index/promise` will then show a specific topic

If you also need to access the selected category in `Topic/index`, add it as an argument:

```
class Topic extends MY_Controller{

    public function index($topic = null, $category = null){

        if($topic == null){
            // here show all topics using model of the selected category
        }

        else{
            // show data of selected topic
        }

    }

}
```

And change the route to pass the category from the url onto the method:

```
$route['category/(:any)/topic/(:any)'] = "topic/index/$2/$1";
```

Comment: I don't want to include index in url like this one: 
domain.com/category/index/js

Comment: Then add another route to remove the index: `$route['category/(:any)'] = "category/index/$1";`